# Nodejs reverse proxy for static files not working with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup Angular + Nodejs behind Ngnix on Ubuntu.

Everything is working fine for Angular and Nodejs API but I'm not able to serve static files.

Here is my configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default):

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    # preflight requests
    if ( $request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" true;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        return 200;
    }
}

location /static {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

The /api route works fine but /static doesn't.

On local, /static works fine because there is no nginx.

I have following directory structure to serve static files:

```
public
   static
     images
     css
     fonts
```

https://somewebsite.com/api/read  (works fine)

https://localhost:3000/static/images/test.png (works fine)

https://somewebsite.com/static/images/test.png

is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`https://localhost:3000/static/images/test.png (works fine)` and `https://somewebsite.com/static/images/test.png` is as expected. According to your configuration, you are also redirecting `/static` to port `7777`: `proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;`

Changing:
`proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;`
to:
`proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;`
should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with following entry:

```
location /static/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_pass "http://localhost:7777/static/";

    # preflight requests
    if ( $request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" true;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        return 200;
    }
}
```